# nginx allow large URIs

Tags: nginx, uri

Where do I specify large_client_header_buffers? I tried inside my server block but recieved this in return:

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k

[....] Restarting nginx: nginxnginx: [emerg] directive "large_client_header_buffers" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:254
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Where do I specify it? The issue is that I need to allow long URI's.

The URI in question is here: http://pastebin.com/Lj4tUEee

Comment: You have missed a ";" according to the error

Comment: Thank you, I added it now but still my URI is to long. What is the max setting for this?

Comment: How big is your URI? What error is being logged in error.log?

Comment: It is very big. The error log show's nothing. Nginx return a 411 To big URI.

This is my URI http://pastebin.com/Lj4tUEee

Comment: I think you're going to have problems with a URI of that size. It is not just based on server but client also. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers for further details.